# Android gradle signConfigs from local file not allowing run configuration from IDE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

so i want to create a signing configuration for any release flavor i have in android.  but i'd like to be able to run it from the IDE by hitting the run button instead of going to build --->generate signed Apk.

I want the credentials and path to the keystore to be seperated out from the application. So i created a properties in my projects app folder.

lets take a look at what i have done so far:

`gradle.properties` file looks like this:

```
myapp.properties=.signing/myapp_signing.properties
```

the content of the property file looks like this:

```
keystore=/Users/Fred/Documents/mykey_ks.jks
keystore.alias_pw=abcd1234
```

and then i have the following to actually get the information from the proerties file into the signingConfig closure:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


if (project.hasProperty("myapp.properties")
        && new File(project.property("myapp.properties")).exists()) {

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("myapp.properties"))))
    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(props['keystore'])
                storePassword props['keystore.password']
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 26
//....... more android stuff below, should be ok to have two android closures right ?


}
```

Now when i press the run button on android studio after selecting ProdRelease i am getting a warning that my apk is not signed and no signing configuration is available ? why ?

[image]

**UPDATE**: i tried the following in build.gradle app level file:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            releaseBuild()
        }
    }
//....
def releaseBuild(){
    if (project.hasProperty("pomelo.properties")
            && new File(project.property("pomelo.properties")).exists()) {

        println 'file does exist'
        Properties props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("myapp.properties"))))
        storeFile file(props['keystore'])
        storePassword props['keystore.password']
        keyAlias props['keystore.alias']
        keyPassword props['keystore.alias_password']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's should be defined like this

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
      releaseBuild()
      .....
    }
}


def releaseBuild(){
if (project.hasProperty("myapp.properties")
        && new File(project.property("myapp.properties")).exists()) {

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("myapp.properties"))))
    storeFile file(props['keystore'])
    storePassword props['keystore.password']
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this but same results. when i hit the run button in android studio it tells me the variant is not signed. same as the image screenshot i showed in my question. have you tried it ?

Comment: the println statement "file does exist" is never called.  in my updated answer